# Scanning, and overriding autofac registrations that use WithParameter

Tags: autofac

As part of my autofac initialization, I scan a list of assemblies and register any services that match a naming convention: MyClass: IMyClass.  This cuts down on the amount of registration code I have so I really don't want to eliminate this feature.  The problem is that I have a couple classes that I want to register using some specific initialization data.  I'm currently registering these after the scanning process using something like:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>().WithParameter("initData", value)
```

When I examine the container I can see both registrations, the one from the scanning process and the one with the specified parameter.  Is this the correct behavior?  I was wanting autofac to replace the scanned registration for IMyClass.  How can I get autofac to use the registration using the provided parameter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container will keep both registrations, but only the last registration will be used. Have you made a test to verify the behavior you expect? Something along these lines:

```
var my = container.Resolve<IMyClass>();
Assert.That(my.Data, Is.EqualTo("initData"));
```

Comment: At your suggestion, I wrote the test and it works as expected.  Seems a  little strange to see multiple registrations in the container but that doesn't matter as long as it resolves correctly and it does.  I'm not sure why this wasn't working in my app code.  Must be something else...